# Mouse doesn't work on splits in Vim for WSL

Tags: vim, mouse, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Ubuntu on a Windows machine via WSL and Vim as my editor. I have `set mouse=a` active which works fine normally. However, when I do a `:vsplit`, the mouse isn't able to select the second split.

Clicking on the split doesn't move the cursor. Selecting text does it at the window level and doesn't enter visual mode in Vim. The scroll wheel also only works in the first split.

Is there a way to get the second split to behave like the first split? I am able to get the desired behavior in Cygwin if that helps.

Comment: Is it possible your mouse setting is getting reset somehow? Does it happen if you start `vim -u NONE --noplugin`?

Comment: @Heptite No, that didn't work. I don't think it's getting reset, because it still works fine on the first split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the mouse actually just stopped working past the 95th column (which is exactly where my split was). I believe this is related to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000960/in-vim-why-doesnt-my-mouse-work-past-the-220th-column

and setting `set ttymouse=sgr` makes it work correctly.